# After Animation EditText is focused for typing

Tags: java, android, animation, focus, focusable

I am trying to have my EditText Focused after the animation to expand it takes place. I tried programmicly setting the focus and in Xml have tried. I have run out of ideas that could fix this but someone out there has to know

MainActivity,

```
public void onSearchExpand(View view){
    w_SearchBarFullScreen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    SearchBarExpand = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,R.anim.web_search_expand);
    w_SearchBarFullScreen.startAnimation(SearchBarExpand);
    w_Toolbar.startAnimation(FadeOut);
    w_SearchBarFullScreen.setFocusable(true);
}
```

XMl,

```
<EditText 
android:id="@+id/w_SearchBarFullScreen"
android:layout_width="360dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:background="@drawable/web_search_bar"
android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
android:inputType="text"
android:maxLines="1"
android:singleLine="true"
android:text="   "
android:elevation="5dp"
android:focusable="true"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

The end goal is that when the Animation finishes it will have the SoftKeyBoard visible and ready to type something into it.

Ended up figuring it out with this,

```
public void onSearchExpand(View view){
    w_SearchBarFullScreen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

   SearchBarExpand = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,R.anim.web_search_expand);
   w_SearchBarFullScreen.startAnimation(SearchBarExpand);
   w_Toolbar.startAnimation(FadeOut);

   if(w_SearchBarFullScreen.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
       w_SearchBarFullScreen.requestFocus();


   }

}
```

but now the issue is having the keyboard show with it getting focus any suggestions?

With the Use of a Animation Listener i am left with this error

```
01-31 13:35:27.411 5950-5950/com.example.mickeyt.onyxbrowser 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.mickeyt.onyxbrowser, PID: 5950

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for 
android:onClick
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5623)
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5623) 
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762) 
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.animation.Animation.setAnimationListener(android.view.animation.Animation$AnimationListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.example.mickeyt.onyxbrowser.MainActivity.onSearchExpand(MainActivity.java:338)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5623) 
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

Comment: and why you dont put  w_SearchBarFullScreen.setFocusable(false); ?

Comment: @EquiWare See my answer , how to show up the soft keybard covers in that as well..

Comment: See new Edit for why Logcat with AnimationListener

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using this worked for me.

```
 public void onSearchExpand(View view){
    w_SearchBarFullScreen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

   w_SearchBarFullScreen.startAnimation(SearchBarExpand);
   w_Toolbar.startAnimation(FadeOut);

   if(w_SearchBarFullScreen.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
       w_SearchBarFullScreen.requestFocus();
       w_SearchBarFullScreen.setText("   ");
       InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)   getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
       assert imm != null;
       imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a listener, which will be triggered when animation is finished so do this

```
FadeOut.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation anim){};
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation anim){};
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim)
    {
        // as mentioned by lib4
        w_SearchBarFullScreen.requestFocus();
    };
});
```

because, currently you are requesting for focus , before animation is finished

or you can try adding it via xml as

```
<EditText  ...>
    <requestFocus/>
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably try this, one important think you can use **requestFocus()** to gain focus.

```
SearchBarExpand.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
               w_SearchBarFullScreen.requestFocus();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });

SearchBarExpand.start();
```

If incase EditText gain focus but didnt show up the keyboard then you should try the below in onAnimationEnd():-

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

    if(w_SearchBarFullScreen.requestFocus()) {
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: An error arrises with the Animation Listener, I am thinking its how I put it in

Comment: Is it animation not starting? did u called SearchBarExpand.start();?

Comment: sorry but i ended up figuring it out check the the update

Comment: getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
 use this to show the keyboard

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164300/discussion-between-equiware-and-lib4).